# Accessing an attribute on a foreign table by joining two tables in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model, `Message` that belongs to the model `User` and the `User` model has an attribute `name`.

Message:

| user_id | message_body |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "hello world" |

User:

| user_id | name. |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "johndoe" |

The result I want is a complete list of all the messages and the respective user name that created each of those messages.

the api controller endpoint looks something like:

```
def index
  @messages = Message.all
  render json: { messages: @messages }
end
```

The issue is that when I return `@messages` it only contains the `user_id` that each message belongs to. What I really want is the user name

I could loop through every message and construct an entirely new object that looks something like:

```
@object = [
  { 
    name: @messages[0].user.name,
    message_body: @messages[0].body
  }, 
  { 
    name: @messages[1].user.name,
    message_body: @messages[1].body
  },
  
  etc.
]
```

and then call `render json: { messages: @object }`

This would probably work fine, but it seems inefficient. Is there a better method for joining these tables for this result?

| name | message body |
| --- | --- |
| "johndoe" | "hello world" |

I was hoping the above example would be enough to get the answer I'm looking for. This is a simplified version of my architecture. In reality it's a bit more complicated:

```
LeagueChatMessage belongs_to LeagueChat 
LeagueChatMessage belongs_to User
LeagueChat belongs_to League
League has_one LeagueChat
```

so this is really what the controller looks like

```
def index
  @league = League.find_by(id: 1) 
  render json: { messages: @league.league_chat.league_chat_messages }
end
```

it works fine. It returns all the league chat messages for the league with the `id: 1` but it returns the `user_id` for each message instead of the user name

Answer (score 0):

Use following logic

```
@data = Message.includes(:user)
```

Now you can use like below

```
@data.each do |msg|
     puts "Message #{msg.body}"
     puts "User #{msg.user.name}"
 end
```

I used puts for understanding but you can use this object in views as you want. And your approach leads to an n+1 query problem, so I used the includes, which helps remove the n+1 query. Try this and let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: This code works but how is the performance improved? calling `render json: { data: @data }` does not display the usernames or any of the columns associated with the user table. Since this is an `each` loop, it still appears to be looping through n times

Comment: after toying around with it a bit, I finally got something I can live with. However, the structure is a bit weird
`render json: @messages, :include => {:user => {:only => :username}}`

Comment: of course its each loop but the object we are sending joins the associated data so no problem. you can just render `render json: { data: @data }`

Comment: when using Rails as an API for another front end such as React, rendering the JSON in this manner does not work. The only items sent via JSON are those attributes attached to the `Message` table. Attributes on the User table, such as `username` are not accessible

Comment: you have to serialize the object.